# Magento2 view Left nagivation is not loading at Participant Cours page

Tags: magento2.3

Sorry, when i click menu i created (Participant Course), i don't know why I can't load the magento interface

[image]

[image]

This is my customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-custom">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">course/manage/course</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Participant Course</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Please help me!

Comment: show your layout xml

Comment: sorry? name file xml

Answer (score 0):

The links of left section of my account pages mydasboard, my Order, My wishlist etc are managed from the layout XML file called `customer_account.xml`.

Checkout file `https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`

That file `customer_account.xml` need to called on that specific using `<update handle="customer_account"/>`

See How the sales history page show the [link](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml)

Same you need to do for your  layout  XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
```

Comment: it not workingg, i edited mu questtions with file xml